# How can I generate an asset URL in JSON using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, json-ld, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using webpack with htmlWebpackPlugin and a custom template to generate an html document. At the bottom of the page, I would like to include a JSON-LD snippet that includes structured data about our company. Normally, that would look something like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name" : "Company Name",
    "url" : "https://www.company.com",
    "logo" : "https://www.company.com/images/logo.png"
  }
</script>
```

However, since I'm using webpack, that asset URL needs to be dynamically generated. I thought about doing something like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" src="./schema.json" />
```

Unfortunately, webpack's JSON loader doesn't provide a way to resolve asset URLs, and for good reason – something like this would be bad practice, because it would result in people creating invalid JSON files:

```
{
  ...
  "logo" : require('./schema.json'),
  ...
}
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed? This is the first webpack use case that I've found that I don't immediately see a beautiful solution to.